# Deducing formula from a given set of formulas

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Having a set of formulas:
$$
S = \big\{ p ⇒ (r \wedge p), \neg p \wedge s, s \vee (p ⇒ q)\big\}
$$
I have to find a formula that can be deduced from this set of formulas. The answer we are looking for (according to the textbook) is 
$$
\neg q \vee s \vee r
$$
Could anyone give me advice on how to solve this type of problem? How to deduce a formula? I have found some advice about writing the set in a [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) and then trying to resolve it, however I'm stuck with the rewritten formulas:

1. ¬p ∨ r
2. ¬p ∨ p
3. ¬p
4. s
5. s ∨ ¬p ∨ q

Where 1. and 2. comes from `S[0]`, 3. and 4. from `S[1]` and 5. from `S[2]`.

Comment: "Natural deduction" will often include the negation of a conclusion, with the goal of reaching a contradiction.  The set of assumptions (in this case $S$) will then be seen to imply the conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your [Formal System's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) [Rules of Inferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) allows [Conjunction Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) and [Disjunction Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction), you may deduce several well-formed formulas from your starting set, including that which your textbook describes.

Expanding on [Bram28](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/256001/bram28)'s answer, starting from $\neg p \land s$, use Conjunction elimination to deduce $s$.

$\neg p \land s \vdash s$

From there, you can use Disjunction Introduction to introduce the required disjuncts (and others). E.g.

$s \vdash s \lor \neg q$

and then

$s \lor \neg q \vdash s \lor \neg q \lor r$

which you can rearrange because of associativity of $\lor$ into

$\neg q \lor s \lor r$

Answer (score 1):

If $s$ is true, then $\neg q \lor s \lor r$ is true as well.

Comment: While your statement is correct, it doesn't go very far to presenting a formal deduction as the OP seems to call for.